# "Weeks of rain/raining"? "Weeks of fight/fighting"? Is there a rule to use the gerund in those examples?

Tags: verbs, nouns, gerunds

It’s common and correct to use both *after two weeks of rain* and *after two weeks of fighting*. But since *fight* is also a noun, couldn’t it be used instead of *fighting*?

Also, why *rain* and not *raining*? Is there a rule of thumb to apply those or is it something you just have to “go with common sense” with?

Comment: "It is April as I write. The wind / Is blowing after days of constant rain." — Wallace Stevens, "The Connoisseur of Chaos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say "*quantity* of *x*" without article in front of *x*, whatever *x* is, it must be an uncountable noun.  The word *fight* can be used uncountably; it means "the propensity or willingness to fight".  You can say, "That girl has a lot of fight in her", but "Two weeks of fight" makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

*Fighting* and *rain* are both nouns, so basically you use whichever noun you have had two weeks of, no matter what it ends in.

Compare:

- > After two weeks of rain

  — The rain went on for two weeks
- > After two weeks of fighting

  — The fighting went on for two weeks

With the second example it's therefore wrong to say "after two weeks of fight" because you are trying to say that there was continuous, generalised fighting over a sustained period.

"The fight went on for two weeks" means one particular fight lasted for two weeks. You would then have to rephrase this as "after two weeks of *the* fight".

A noun with the *-ing* ending formed from a verb is called a gerund, and there are many examples — see *ending* in this very sentence. Some of them are so common that we don't notice them, like *ending*, but others stand out as more unusual.

Comment: So are _raining_ and _fight_ nouns. The point is that _rain_ and _fighting_ are **mass** nouns, whereas _fight_ is not (at least not in that sense, as Malvolio points out)